# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' - com.google.android.gms

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, build.gradle

I don't know what I am doing wrong, this message keeps appearing every time I try to sync the gradle file:

[image]

[image]

The error I'm getting:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change those:

```
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
```

to this:

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
```

and then sync, 11.8.0 is the latest version.

Check this to see the latest firebase versions: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android